# Foundation 5 Simple Navigation

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

how is possible to make simple top menu in foundation 5? Is needed to use topbar or is there any other possibility? My actual code is:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
    <h1><a href="#">Site Name</a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Domov</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

But i have problem with mobile version. Navigation is broken and jumps under menu not collapse in simple button. Can someone tell me why? and how to fix it, or make more simple navigation? Thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure to include the necessary javascript files and `$(document).foundation();`?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle

Comment: you can see current versoin here: http://sauny.osuchane.sk/ login: dev password: developer . try to resize monitor and you will se main problem.

Comment: Make a fiddle please, link to your own page isn't a good example because it cannot be edited in real time by someone who is trying to help you and it also isn't as explanatory as a fiddle is. Finally, fiddle is less complexier so it is easier to find a bug. Anyway, greetings from CZ :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard foundation .top-bar navigation. Don't forget to include the necessary js files and initialize them as well.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
     <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: yes, but that is standard version, I need something different. You can see current version here: sauny.osuchane.sk login: dev password: developer . try to resize monitor and you will se main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
.top-bar {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tjscsmL6/18/)

Comment: This is not solving my problem, I think there will be some problem with breakpoint of topbar navigation and I have no idea how to change it. It seems that topbar always change to "mobile version" around 625px no metter how much menu items are inside.

Answer (score 0):

I think , instead of using topbar , you can use iconbar which will easily meet your requirement . UI will be same for mobile as well as for desktop version .
Check below link:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/icon-bar.html